# Parse a list from string SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, parsing

I have been using this function to parse a list of strings; is there a more efficient way to do this?

This is to parse a string having multi values.

This is how I use the function

```
select * 
from dbo.fn_getlistfromstring(''1,3,2,46,Mums the Order,bb'')
```

Function code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_getlistfromstring]
     (@string NVARCHAR(4000), 
      @separator NVARCHAR(50))
RETURNS @list TABLE
              (value NVARCHAR(200) collate database_default)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @working NVARCHAR(4000), @value NVARCHAR(150)
    DECLARE @startpos INT, @endpos INT, @len INT, @seplen INT

    IF LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(@string, ''))) <> '' 
    BEGIN
        SET @seplen = LEN(@separator)
        SET @working = LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(@string, '')))

        IF CHARINDEX(@separator, @working, 1) <> 0 
        BEGIN
            SET @len = LEN(@working)
            SET @startpos = 1
      set @endpos = 1
      set @value = ''
      while @endpos < @len and @startpos < @len
        begin
        set @endpos = charindex(@separator, @working,@startpos)
        if @endpos = 0
          set @endpos = @len + 1
        set @value = ltrim(rtrim(substring( @working, @startpos, (@endpos - @startpos))))
        INSERT into @list (value) values (@value)
        set @startpos = @endpos + @seplen
        end
      end
    else -- only one
      INSERT into @list (value) values (@working)
    end

 RETURN 
END


GO
```

Comment: There are far better ways, yes. For example one SQL Server 2016+ there is `STRING_SPLIT`. You also have a method using `FOR XML PATH`, Jeff Moden's `DelmimitedSplit8K`, and many other answers. This is a very frequent question on SO; so I suggest having a search first on your preferred Search Engine.. :)

Comment: Besides the good points of @Larnu, don't forget CLR, it will outperform all SQL based approaches.

Comment: Here is Jeff Moden's http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/ And several other great options here. https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings CLR will definitely be faster but if you are using a tsql solution it should NOT have any looping or recursive ctes.

Comment: "Parse" is for more complex transformations. If you search for "Split", then you will find that this question has been answered several times.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies and for the 2016+ trick as we are switching in a few months to that version. I do not know how I missed Jeff Moden's post when searching!

Comment: Hi folks, I have been reading a bit on CLR and sorry for the newb question but is this .net and SQL mixture?